# custom URL for MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

i have been trying to write a route that would allows something like this

```
routes.MapRoute(
          name: "UserName",
          url: "{username}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );
```

routes could be

http://localhost/salman/

http://localhost/salman/login

http://localhost/login

in my case username is optional so it may be possible username is available in URL or not so if username is not available then it should consider it as controller

rite now its not possible through routes . i thought to write a custom implementation that will check if First part is username or not

Need expert opinion how to achieve above

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is achievable when you add one more route as follows

```
routes.MapRoute(
          name: "Login",
          url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );
```

you can have multiple routes for same controller and action. Unless i have made mistake in understanding your question.

Comment: I have multiple controllers in system and it will be quite difficult to add routes for each of them . i wanted to have something generic so i can make a check in code and then move to rite controller

Comment: you will need to specify the routes for this particular scenario, not for every controller.

Comment: that would be  Salman/ login , salman/register , salman/activation etc :S  thats what i m trying to avoid as there could be many scenarios in the system